# PDF_Extraction of structured data without OCR

Tags: c#, automation, automationanywhere

I have been trying to extract data including the once in tables from pdf files using C#.My objective is to extract these data without any third party library and its licensing  or OCRs at the same time extract the data without loosing its structure.I need this for creating a DLL for pdf automation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe, the best way to achieve this is using a library called iTextSharp. It is easily available as a Nuget package.

Following is an example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;

namespace Pdf2Text
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!args.Any()) return;

            var file = args[0];
            var output = Path.ChangeExtension(file, ".txt");
            if (!File.Exists(file)) return;

            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
            File.WriteAllText(output, ConvertToText(bytes), Encoding.UTF8);
        }

        private static string ConvertToText(byte[] bytes)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            try
            {
                var reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
                var numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;

                for (var currentPageIndex = 1; currentPageIndex <= numberOfPages; currentPageIndex++)
                {
                    sb.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, currentPageIndex));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. - Since you don't need an OCR solution, this way would work. But it will not work if the PDF has data in images. For that only OCR would be a solution.

Give it a try and let me know your comments.

Comment: Yes, I've used it for multiple clients. It's available for free under Nuget distribution.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.IO;

namespace PDF_EXTRACT
{

    public class pdfTohtm
    {

        public static string ConvertPdf(string path, string outpath)
        {
            Word.Application app = new Word.Application(); ;
            Word.Document doc1;
            try
            {

                doc1 = app.Documents.Open(path, false, ReadOnly: false);
                app.DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsAll;
                app.FileValidation = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoFileValidationMode.msoFileValidationSkip;
                app.Visible = false;
                app.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;
                doc1.SaveAs2(outpath, Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML, ReadOnlyRecommended: false);
                doc1.Close();
                string result = File.ReadAllText(outpath + ".htm", Encoding.UTF7);
                return "success:" + result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {


                return "failed::::" + e;


            }
            finally
            {
                app.Quit();
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app);
            }

        }
    }



}
```

Explanation:  This solution  works by opening pdf as a editable word document, then the file is saved as
.htm file. Now the .htm file is opened and read as a textfile,thus the output of this code is a set of html codes, which you can paste in you Excel to convert to pdf to Excel without loosing the structure of the data.

KEY NOTES:

1. This solution does not work if the pdf is a scanned copy,for such
   pdfs OCR seems to be the only option as per my little knowledge on
   the subject.

2.For argument "path" the full path of file must be
        passed and for the argument "outpath" pass the path without
        extension eg:C:\Users\username\folder\filename (no extension of
        file i.e. ".htm" required).